# Getting infinite loop in angular js controller, Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig]

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html

JSP (part of the code)

```
<tr ng-repeat="eachlowerstack in configdata.lowerstack">
    <td>
        <p ng-model="detail(eachlowerstack.integration.id)">{{eachlowerstack.integration.id}}</p><br>
        <span>Name: {{config.name}}</span><br>
        <span>Platform: {{config.platform}}</span><br>
        <span>Version: {{config.version}}</span><br>
        <span>Level: {{config.level}}</span><br>
    </td>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.detail = function(integid) {


    $scope.url1 = contextPath + "/getlowerstackdetails/"+integid;
    console.log($scope.url1);

    DependecyInject.getData($scope.url1).then(function(result) {
        $scope.config = result.data;
        console.log($scope.config);
        console.log($scope.config.name);
        console.log($scope.config.platform);
        console.log($scope.config.version);
        console.log($scope.config.level);
        //console.log($scope.configdata.lowerstack.integration.id);
    });
};
```

At run time I'm getting a response from the back end but it's going in to an infinite loop:

> angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D

Comment: Your `ngModel` is a function - what do you expect it to do?

Comment: I can't see configData.lowerstack variable on which you are looping ng-repeat

Comment: <tr ng-repeat="eachlowerstack in configdata.lowerstack">
configdata.lowerstack is a json array in that there are more than one integration.id , and for the each integration.id i want to send this parameter to controller that i am doing through
<p  ng-model="detail(eachlowerstack.integration.id)">{{eachlowerstack.integration.id}}</p>
then from the controller i m making the rest api call and getting the response (so currently it is able to make a call but going in the infinite loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "**ng-init**" instead of "ng-model"